# "The options "title", "url" do not exist. Defined options are: ""

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I am following this tutorial:

https://sonata-project.org/bundles/block/master/doc/reference/your_first_block.html

I am able to save a new block, but when I try to use the `remove` button in order to remove the block, my logs show this error:

> request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Exception\UndefinedOptionsException:
>   "The options "title", "url" do not exist. Defined options are: ""." at
>   /usr/src/app/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/OptionsResolver/OptionsResolver.php
>   line 685

**Where do I need to define my fields in order to fix this issue? And what would that definition look like if adhering to the tutorial in question?**

====

Edit 1: Here is the content of my block service:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Block;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Sonata\BlockBundle\Model\BlockInterface;
use Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\BlockContextInterface;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\CoreBundle\Validator\ErrorElement;
use Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\Service\AbstractBlockService;
use Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\Service\AbstractAdminBlockService;

class PatrickBlockService extends AbstractAdminBlockService
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'url'      => false,
            'title'    => 'Insert the rss title',
            'template' => '@SonataBlock/Block/block_core_rss.html.twig',
        ));
    }

    public function buildEditForm(FormMapper $formMapper, BlockInterface $block)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('settings', 'sonata_type_immutable_array', array(
                'keys' => array(
                    array('url', 'url', array('required' => false)),
                    array('title', 'text', array('required' => false)),
                )
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function validateBlock(ErrorElement $errorElement, BlockInterface $block)
    {
        $errorElement
            ->with('settings.url')
            ->assertNotNull(array())
            ->assertNotBlank()
            ->end()
            ->with('settings.title')
            ->assertNotNull(array())
            ->assertNotBlank()
            ->assertMaxLength(array('limit' => 50))
            ->end()
        ;
    }

    public function execute(BlockContextInterface $blockContext, Response $response = null)
    {
        // merge settings
        $settings = $blockContext->getSettings();
        $feeds = false;

        if ($settings['url']) {
            $options = array(
                'http' => array(
                    'user_agent' => 'Sonata/RSS Reader',
                    'timeout' => 2,
                )
            );

            // retrieve contents with a specific stream context to avoid php errors
            $content = @file_get_contents($settings['url'], false, stream_context_create($options));

            if ($content) {
                // generate a simple xml element
                try {
                    $feeds = new \SimpleXMLElement($content);
                    $feeds = $feeds->channel->item;
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    // silently fail error
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->renderResponse($blockContext->getTemplate(), array(
            'feeds'     => $feeds,
            'block'     => $blockContext->getBlock(),
            'settings'  => $settings
        ), $response);
    }
}
```

... and here is the relevant content from admin.yml:

```
app.block.service.patrick:
    class: AppBundle\Block\PatrickBlockService
    arguments:
        - "Patrick Block"
        - "@templating"
```

So far, I have tried removing the two fields involved from the configureOptions() method, and that does not seem to make a difference.

====

Edit 2:

When I say "I am aboe to save a new block," I mean that the information gets saved in the database and is available for later retrieval. However, I see the same error during that step.

Comment: You should isolate more the problem, many people don't have time to do the tutorial all along with you

Comment: Add the code you’re using so we can see what you’ve written

Comment: BTW, have you defined the configureOptions method?

Comment: @vivoconunxino: I have indeed defined configureOptions. Good question.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone googling this years later: I ended up giving up on the tutorial and going in the opposite direction by basically forking the existing logic that Sonata provides. Here's a vague version of what I remember doing:

- Cloned the file at `vendor/sonata-project/block-bundle/Block/Service/RssBlockService.php` into `src/AppBundle/Block/RssBlockService.php`
- Updated `admin.yml` and `sonata_block.yml` accordingly.
- Ran `tail -f var/logs/dev.log` and adjusted my `use` statements to patch up any remaining rough spots.
- Created a new Twig template and adjusted my code to use that template.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is confusing in this case.

It is not the default options you need to set here, but rather the default settings, but since both options and settings use OptionsResolver class, feedback has confusing wording.

```
use Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\Service\AbstractBlockService;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class MyBlockService extends AbstractBlockService
{
    public function configureSettings(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'url'      => false,
            'title'    => 'Insert the rss title',
            'template' => '@SonataBlock/Block/block_core_rss.html.twig',
        ));
    }
}
```

- my example uses AbstractBlockService which AbstractAdminBlockService extends from.